How do I extend the trendline from graph 1[out71] to graph 2[out187]?
Screenshot
I would like to extend the y-lim and x-lim also the trend line to make two graphs look like the same. So I set truncate as False, then I update the ylim and xlim after, the trend line didn't extend to the new xy limit.
Feels like both x-lim and ylim needs to be set before that. How can I do that?
Link to the data: https://github.com/ning733/LearningPython.git
My code for the graph:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv("911.csv")
df["timeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timeStamp"])
df["Month"] = df["timeStamp"].apply(lambda x:x.month)
byMonth = df.groupby("Month").count()
g = sns.lmplot(data = byMonth.reset_index(), x = "Month", y = "twp", truncate = False)
g.set(ylim=(6000,15000), xlim=(0,14))


Please provide a [mre] of your current code+data. Images of code are not acceptable.
